# Variable scope in d3 when callback is an event function

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I know there are many questions here about how to globalize the scope of variables that have been updated inside a json callback function. And I have been trying to work off those examples for days now but I cant seem to work out how I can adapt that to my code when my json callbacks are on an event eg.on right click(context menu). I have been trying to use this example but have not been successful to try and adapt it to my code:

```
function myFunc(data) {
console.log(data);
}

d3.json('file.json', function (data) {
var json = data;
myFunc(json);
}
```

I am working with a scatterplot in d3. My first connection just adds two rows of my table into both of the arrays. Each row represents a dot. When I click on one of these dots, a connection is made to the database and links to that selected dot appear on the graph as other dots. And these are added to the baseData array and the libraryData remains the same. WHen I right click on one of these dots that dot is added to the libraryData array.But as indicated in the code, instances of libraryData outside of the function has not been updated. Below is my code

```
var libraryData = [];
var baseData = [];


d3.json("connection4.php", function(error,dataJson) {

dataJson.forEach(function(d) {
    d.YEAR = +d.YEAR;  
    d.counter = +d.counter;
    libraryData.push(d);
    baseData.push(d);
    })

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(libraryData) // libraryData here remains unchanged even after librayData has been updated in the function below!
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(YearFn(d))})
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(Num_citationsFn(d))})
        .style("fill","blue") 
        .on("click", clickHandler)

function clickHandler (d, i) {

    d3.json("connection2.php?paperID="+d.ID, function(error, dataJson) {

                dataJson.forEach(function(d) {

                    d.YEAR = +d.YEAR;
                    d.counter = +d.counter;

                baseData.push(d);   

                })

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
                                .data(baseData) 
                                .enter()
                                .append("circle")
                                .attr("class", "dot")
                                .attr("r", 3.5)
                                .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(YearFn(d))})
                                .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(Num_citationsFn(d))})
                                .style("fill", "red") 
                                .on("contextmenu", rightClickHandler);
})

function rightClickHandler (d, i) {

    d3.json("connection6.php?paperID="+d.ID, function(error, dataJson) {

                })

            d3.select(this)
                .style("fill", "blue");

        libraryData.push(d);
        console.log(libraryData);// updated

    }
console.log(libraryData)// not updated

});
```

I am new to d3 and I would appreciate any help and feedback thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

It's not scope, it's a timing issue

```
function rightClickHandler (d, i) {

    d3.json("connection6.php?paperID="+d.ID, function(error, dataJson) {

                })

            d3.select(this)
                .style("fill", "blue");

        libraryData.push(d);
        console.log("I bet I'm second", libraryData);// updated

    }
console.log("I bet I'm first", libraryData)// not updated

});
```

the`function(error, dataJson)` in the json call only executes once json is returned from your php function which can take a while. Meanwhile, your program performs the second call to console.log runs straight away and before the function in the json call has added anything to libraryData.

Run the above with the changes to console.log to see

Basically anything you want to do that depends on library data being updated must be called inside `function(error, dataJson)`